# Adding Additional Messages to Authorize.net Responses

Tags: authorize.net

I am attempting to add some more useful messages for various error codes that are returned from Authorize (Using the AcceptJS) as the error configuration only has four out of the box.

I have added the `authorizenet_acceptjs_error_mapping.xml` file under a custom module in the following manner, but my updated responses/codes are not being utilized.

```
-VENDOR
--MODULE
---etc
----authorizenet_acceptjs_error_mapping.xml
```

Do I need to do something else in order for Magento to utilize my error mapping file instead of the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, the missing step was to override the location of the `VirtualConfigReader` in your `di.xml` file like so:

```
<virtualType name="AuthorizenetAcceptjsErrorMappingConfigReader" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\ErrorMapper\VirtualConfigReader">
    <arguments>
        <!-- Updated filename to prevent issue with "more than one node" error -->
        <argument name="fileName" xsi:type="string">authorizenet_error_mapping.xml</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```